# ImportError: libboost_python.so.1.41.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, debian, boost-python, pyv8

I am trying to install PyV8 to debian (I tried to ubuntu too)according the steps here http://www.wikisecure.net/importing-pyv8-engine-into-python-v2-7-the-easy-way/

However I always get *ImportError: libboost_python.so.1.41.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*

I installed boost using apt-get install. I tried many manuals, how to install PyV8, but nothing work, so if anyone has something that worked or how fix my error, I would be pleased.

Thanks for advice

Comment: Which Boost package(s) did you install? Boost consists of a bunch of libraries, most of which are header-only and so are installed together on Debian and Ubuntu, but binary libraries like libboost-python are packaged separately. Installing libboost-all-dev is the easiest way to get all of Boost.

Comment: I installed libbost-all-dev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing libboost-all-dev, the file you're missing should be in there.

For clarity: What actually worked was copying and renaming a later version of libboost to 1.41. I would not recommend this as a fist solution, if getting the correct version is an option.

Comment: I did this before.

Comment: have you looked into your library path? It's very possible you have installed a higher version. I see you are using python 2, and are looking for a rather old boost version.

Comment: I am using python 2.7. Where I can find library path? I am not sure, what  you mean.

Comment: /usr/local/lib If you are on Ubuntu or Arch, if not, google helps.

Comment: I have there python2.7, python 3.4, x86_64-linux-gnu

Comment: There should be a lot of .so files in there. one of which should start with libboost_python...

Comment: There are: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34.a
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so.1.55.0
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34.so
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34.so.1.55.0
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.a
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.a

Comment: As i suspected, you have installed a higher version, 1.55 in this case. You now have a few options:
1) Upgrade your software so it uses current boost versions.
2) Downgrade your boost installation or install a separate older boost package.
3) COPY and rename the libboost_python.so.1.55.0 file to libboost_python.so.1.41.0 and pray that it works.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I am afraid, there is no newer version of PyV8. I will try option 2 or option 3.

Comment: I am trying to install older version, but I get Error: Dependency is not satisfiable, and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Probably  because the older version requires older dependencies that aren't in the repositories anymore. Try the renaming option.